# Posting a file image with retrofit

Tags: android, json, django, retrofit, multipart

I want to know if i can post a file image that is inside of a POJO model.
does the request has to be with POST or do i have to make it a multipart?
thanks!
I have read many thing bout doing it with multipart with one part being the image and the other one being the description, but I need a hole body, How do I do that?
my POJO models holds, username, phone number and the file picture.

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface FileUploadService {
    @Multipart
    @POST("/api/users/{user_id}")
    Call<String> upload(
            @Path("user_id") String user_id,
            @Header("Authorization") String authorization,
            @Part("profile_img\"; filename=\"image.png\" ") RequestBody file);

}
```

you can add other parameters like username and phonenumber with part parameters as well.